# Spring Transaction if the this duplicated key gives the exception, but it does not do the Rollback (Updated code to detect better the error)

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions

In the Transaction if there is an exception for duplicate of key, that happens in the second persist, , the first one it persists and does not do the Rollback, and this one remains recorded in the database. **(Updated question with more code to detect better the error)**

```
      public interface TemperaturesDao {
        @Transactional (rollbackFor=Throwable.class)
    // @Transactional (rollbackFor=Exception.class) // changed
        void save(JavaTemperatures jT);
    }

    @Repository
    public class TemperaturesDaoImp implements TemperaturesDao{
        @Autowired
        private SessionFactory sf;
        @Transactional (rollbackFor=Throwable.class)
        // @Transactional (rollbackFor=Exception.class) // changed
        public void save(JavaTemperatures jT) {
            Session session = sf.getCurrentSession();
            session.save(jT);
        }
    }


    public interface TemperaturesService {
        @Transactional (rollbackFor=Throwable.class)
    // @Transactional (rollbackFor=Exception.class) // changed
        void saveService();
    }

    @Service("temperaturesServiceImp")
    public class TemperaturesServiceImp implements TemperaturesService{
        @Autowired
        TemperaturesDao tempeDao;

        @Transactional (rollbackFor=Throwable.class)
    // @Transactional (rollbackFor=Exception.class) // changed
        public void saveService() {
            JavaTemperatures jT = new JavaTemperatures();
            jT.setKey("key2");
            tempeDao.save(jT); // This is registered in the database at the end of the veService

            jT = new JavaTemperatures();
            jT.setKey("key1"); // This key exists in the database
            tempeDao.save(jT); // This record gives exception at the end of the saveService
        }
    }


    public class BaseBeanImp implements Serializable{
        ...
    }

    @Controller
    @Scope("session")
    public class ComparaBean extends BaseBeanImp implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Autowired
        private TemperaturesService tempeService;

        public String doSave() {
            tempeService.saveService() ;
            return null;
        }
    }

    **index.xhtml**
    <h:commandButton value="Save" action="#{comparaBean.doSave}" />
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<beans xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" >
<property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" > </property>
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://redhada.org:3306/db" > </property>
<property name="username" value="username" > </property>
<property name="password" value="password" ></property>
<property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" > </property>
<property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1" ></property>
<property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="1200000" ></property>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean" >
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" > </property>
<property name="annotatedClasses" >
    <list>
    <value>com.redhada.model.JavaTemperatures</value>
    </list>
</property>
<property name="hibernateProperties">
<props><prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop></property>
</bean>
<context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.redhada"></context:component-scan>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<bean id="transactionManager"
 class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager" >
<property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" > </property>
```

**Console:**

```
263194 [http-8080-Processor23] WARN org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
263194 [http-8080-Processor23] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Duplicate entry 'clave31' for key 1
263195 [http-8080-Processor23] ERROR org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Could not synchronize database state with session org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
...
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Duplicate entry 'key1' for key 1
...
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'key1' for key 1
...
```

**But it save the record**

**Why does persist if the second tempeDao.save gives the exception?**

**Why does not do the Rollback?**

Comment: from where are you calling the `saveService` method?

Comment: please check that temperature service implementation is not picked up by autoscanning in the servlet xml context configuration.

Comment: Please add your servlet xml configuration to the question. P.S. Also it's a bad idea to decorate your interfaces with `@Transactional`, you should only put `@Transactional` on your implementation classes/methods.

Answer (score 0):

Changed your `@Transactional (rollbackFor=Exception.class)`

to

```
@Transactional (rollbackFor=Throwable.class)
```

And check.

Comment: I have changed It, but this continues doing the same

Answer (score 0):

You did not show the code that is actually running that calls `saveService()`.  Most likely the invocation is coming from a place that is already behind the Transactional Proxy, so Spring cannot "see" the annotation to start a transaction at that level.  Would be able to tell if you add the code.

Comment: `@Controller

    @Scope("session")

    public class ComparaBean extends BaseBeanImp implements Serializable {

    @Autowired

    private TemperaturesService tempeService;


    public String doSave() {

        tempeService.saveService();

    }

    }`

Comment: That looks fine, but given the code posted in the original question does not compile, there problem may yet be in something you've left out :)

Comment: I changed the code posted in the original question for you detect the error. If you need more code let me know

Answer (score 0):

Apparently tempeDao.save initiate a new transaction every call. so the first call to the save method commit successfully but the second one fail with  duplicate entry exception and rollback.

try to add propagation= Propagation.MANDATORY to the DAO transactional methods.

```
@Transactional (propagation= Propagation.MANDATORY, rollbackFor=Throwable.class)
```

This force dao to use the same transaction of the service. then the rollback will be applied to all.

I don't think you will have this problem with the latest version of spring,

Answer (score 0):

in my case i happen this situation when i update an java pojo,
you can use merge method instead of using update method when you update something already in the java